# Using a SVG shape link in Ember's link-to: markup

Tags: svg, ember.js, imagemap

I am migrating a project from HTML to Ember. I am using an SVG imagemap overlaying a background jpeg image.

When I create "link-to:" links in Ember for the SVG shape "buttons," Ember generates a link within a link that excludes the SVG shape and produces a rectangle that doesn't link to anything.

```html
<!-- the following link creates a link within a link that excludes the rectangle -->
<a>
{{ link-to 'ember link' 'ember-link' }}
<rect id="linkToEmberProblem" x="47" y="460" width="182" height="100"/>
</a>
```

which outputs to this in the browser:

```html
<a>
  <a id="ember373" href="/ember-link" class="ember-view">ember link</a>
  <rect id="linkToEmberProblem" x="47" y="460" width="182" height="100"></rect>
</a>
```

I think I understand why, however placing the SVG shape inside Ember's link-to: link handlebars creates a build error:

Is there a means to preserve SVG shape links within an Ember app?

Below is the full code of the page:

```html
<style>
 /* show location of link */
 
 #linkToEmberProblem {
  fill: rgba(224,64,80, .8);
 }
 
</style>

<div class="canvas">
 <h2>City</h2>

<!-- be sure to use fill=transparent in the svg declaration to avoid the black hole boxes over link areas!
-->
 <svg id="city" data-name="city" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 916.8 711.36" fill=transparent>
  
  <image width="1200" height="800" xlink:href="assets/img/city.jpg"/>
  
  <!-- the following link creates a link within a link that excludes the rectangle -->
  <a>
   {{ link-to 'ember link' 'ember-link' }}
   <rect id="linkToEmberProblem" x="47" y="460" width="182" height="100"/>
  </a>  
  
 </svg>
</div>
```

and its output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the block form for the `link-to` helper. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/templates/links/

```
{{#link-to 'ember-link' }}
   <rect id="linkToEmberProblem" x="47" y="460" width="182" height="100"/>
{{/link-to}}
```

Here is a working example. 
https://ember-twiddle.com/daf349bf31ce68baa7ec9bd89608e85a?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

Comment: That is terrific! Thank you for providing an example to follow. Many thanks!